# Is there anything wrong with this RC4 encryption code in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, arc4random, rc4-cipher

I am trying to listen to the  [Foxycart](http://www.foxycart.com/) [XML Datafeed](http://wiki.foxycart.com/v/0.7.0/advanced/transaction_xml_datafeed) in C# and running into an issue which boils down to encryption.

In short, they send over their data as encoded and encrypted XML using [RC4 encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).

To test, they have [some (user submitted) sample code to test this with C#](http://wiki.foxycart.com/integration/foxycart/datafeed_with_csharp).  I tried using this sample RC4 decryption code provided by one of the users but it doesn't seem to work and their support staff thinks its down with the C# RC4 algorithm.  Since they are not C# experts, i figured i would ask here.  Here is [the post on the FoxyCart forum](http://forum.foxycart.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=4951&page=1#Item_6)

Anyway, here is the code that (tries to) simulate the response by encrypting an XML file and posting it to a URL (NOTE that DataFeedKey is a string that i have stored as a member variable):

```
public ActionResult TestDataFeed()
{
    string transactionData = (new StreamReader(@"D:\SampleFeed.xml")).ReadToEnd();
    string encryptedTransactionData = RC4.Encrypt(DataFeedKey, transactionData, false);
    string encodedTransactionData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryptedTransactionData,     Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
    string postData = "FoxyData=" + encodedTransactionData;
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3396/FoxyCart/RecieveDataFeed");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    sw.Write(postData);
    sw.Close();
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    try
    {
        resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        string r = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        string err = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and here is the callback method that receives the response.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult RecieveDataFeed(FormCollection collection)
{
    string unencodedFeed = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(collection["FoxyData"],     Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
    string transaction = RC4.Decrypt(DataFeedKey, unencodedFeed, false);
    return Content("foxy");
}
```

Instead of posting the whole RC4 class inline in this question, [here is a link to the code of this RC4 class](http://wiki.foxycart.com/integration/foxycart/datafeed_with_csharp).

As i posted in the above link at the top of the question, the issue is when i check the variable transaction inside the

```
 RecieveDataFeed()
```

method, i should have the regular XML back but instead i see this:

```
É?xø´ v´“Û·8êUŸí¥MïSÅJÖó5Cå7ã…ÄlÞ&þòG·¶ÝÙ3<ÍÖ¡«úüF¿¿ßìNµ>4¦Äu÷¼Â;£-w¤ƒûÊyL¹®½èíYö½’é(µJŒ~»»=3¼]F‡•=±Ùí]'é³«"øPç{Ù^yyéå–°ñ…5ðWF$zÉnÄ^_”Xë’ï%œ-5á
ÒÛ€jŠt`Â9œÇÞLU&¼~ç2îžúo/¢¶5,º*öOqÝ—‘.ó®šuf™å5G—õC®‰ÁéiÇúW®¦ÝÚ•Z±:„Q\p"p
ôÔiÛ!\D"ÉÂX3]ƒ°è€Œ«DQE‡kÝ@àö`gpöŽ÷nÛ={µÏßKQKüå(ö%¯¯Ü–9}¨¬°£7yo,«”ÜëCÍ/+…†ÕËî‘‹‰AÚmÇÙå©&©¡xÙkŒföX¯ÃX&×°S|kÜ6Ô°Üú\Ätóü-äUÆ†ÈáÅ\ ’E8‚¤âÈ4Ž¾«ãÎš_Sï£y‰xJº•bm*jo›‰ÜW–[ô†ÆJÐà$½…9½šžˆ_ÙÜù/®öÁVhzŠ¥ú(ñ£²6ˆb6¢ëße¤oáIðZuK}ÆÙ]"T¼*åZêñß5K—½òQSåRN Çë'Å¡
Ã•yiÈX •bØðIk¿WxwNàäx®‹?cv+X™¥E!gd4â¤nÔ‹¢½Ð”ªÊ­Q!‚.e8s
Gyª4¼ò,}Yœ‚¹”±E‡Jy}Sæ
ƒ¦ýK'Ð}~B¦E3!0°ú´A–5Þ³£9$–8äÏ©?
 œ‡8GÂø
```

The code looks right:

1. Encrypt
2. Encode
3. Decode
4. Decrypt

but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions on what might be wrong above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am a bit surprised by the code in the CR4 class. I can't see how it would work reliably.

The code uses windows-1252 encoding to encode characters into bytes, then it encrypts the bytes and tries to decode the bytes into characters. That won't work reliably, as you can only decode bytes that comes from encoding characters.

The method takes a string and returns a string, but it should take a byte array and return a byte array, similar to how all the encryption classes in the framework does it.

Here is a version that works like that:

```
public class RC4 {

  public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] pwd, byte[] data) {
    int a, i, j, k, tmp;
    int[] key, box;
    byte[] cipher;

    key = new int[256];
    box = new int[256];
    cipher = new byte[data.Length];

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      key[i] = pwd[i % pwd.Length];
      box[i] = i;
    }
    for (j = i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      j = (j + box[i] + key[i]) % 256;
      tmp = box[i];
      box[i] = box[j];
      box[j] = tmp;
    }
    for (a = j = i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
      a++;
      a %= 256;
      j += box[a];
      j %= 256;
      tmp = box[a];
      box[a] = box[j];
      box[j] = tmp;
      k = box[((box[a] + box[j]) % 256)];
      cipher[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ k);
    }
    return cipher;
  }

  public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] pwd, byte[] data) {
    return Encrypt(pwd, data);
  }

}
```

Example:

```
string data = "This is a test.";
byte[] key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// encrypt
byte[] enc = RC4.Encrypt(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

// turn into base64 for convenient transport as form data
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(enc);

Console.WriteLine(base64);

// turn back into byte array
byte[] code = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

// decrypt
string dec = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RC4.Decrypt(key, code));

Console.WriteLine(dec);
```

Output:

```
5lEKdtBUswet4yYveWU2
This is a test.
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Am I licensed to use this code in a commercial project?

Comment: @wezten: Yes, you may use it anyway you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is more shooting in the dark... I am rather certain that the class implementing RC4 looks like it is assuming everyting is either ASCII or CodePage 1252 - both is wrong because I assume that the XML supplied is UTF-8 and .NET string represantion in memory is UTF16...

If my assumption is right the data is already scrambled when you get it back from encryption...

EDIT - some links to working RC4 code in C#:

- http://tofuculture.com/Blog/post/RC4-Encryption-in-C.aspx
- http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/rc4-encryption-SID577.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/rc4csharp.aspx
- http://icodesnip.com/snippet/csharp/rc4-encryption-code-snippets

Comment: But decoding UTF-8 as ASCII shouldn't give the mess in the question.

Comment: it is not only the en/decoding process but check the link with the RC4 class of the OP... the encryption itself breaks the encoding badly...